# Edit Text Input in Full Screen Android

Tags: java, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

Can someone help me to put an EditText input Method (android) open in fullscreen mode ?
like this:
[image]

Thank You for the attention

Comment: can you provide more information

Comment: already edit the question

Comment: This is only possible in landscape mode on small displays.